# How to get only one element from collection in the view

Tags: laravel

I passed $users variable to my view and I want to get only one element of this collection by comparing it using contains() method.

It's working but I want to retrieve this element so I can show the name
how to do that?

My code:

```
@foreach($rqs as $rq)
   
<td>{{$rq->user_id}} with name:
                               
@if($users->contains('id',$rq->user_id))
       Working  >> I want to get the user name here but only one user                   
@endif

</td>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
$users->where('id',$rq->user_id)->first()->name
```